# Testing Number Theoretic Functions in Haskell using a recursor over natural numbers

Tags: haskell, recursion, quickcheck, exponentiation

I'm implementing some number theoretic functions as the exponentiation in Haskell using a recursor. I'm using the QuickCheck library for testing my implementation.
For simplify my tests, I'm using the Natural data type from the base library, the
Arbitrary instance for Natural defined in the quickcheck-instances library and the
following functions converting from Nat to Natural and from Natural to Nat, respectively, considering the data Nat defined by myself:

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

natToNatural :: Nat -> Natural
natToNatural Zero = 0
natToNatural (Succ n) = 1 + natToNatural n

naturalToNat :: Natural -> Nat
naturalToNat 0 = Zero
naturalToNat n = Succ (naturalToNat (n - 1))
```

The implemetation use the following recursor over natural numbers:

```
recNat :: a -> (Nat -> a -> a) -> Nat -> a
recNat a _ Zero     = a
recNat a h (Succ n) = h n (recNat a h n)
```

My function of exponentiation is

```
expR :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
expR m n = recNat (Succ Zero) (\ _ y -> multR m y) n
```

I define the prop_Exp property using the exponentiation on Natural

```
prop_Exp :: Natural -> Natural -> Bool
prop_Exp m n = natToNatural (expR m' n') == m ^ n
  where
    m' :: Nat
    m' = naturalToNat m

    n' :: Nat
    n' = naturalToNat n
```

for testing my implementation of the expR function via QuickCheck

```
main :: IO ()
main = quickCheck prop_expR
```

However, after running this code I get an exception:

```
*** Exception: stack overflow
```

I want to know what it is wrong with this code

Comment: I guess that such test could generate random numbers which are too large for exponentiation. Keep in mind that your `Nat` type represents numbers in unary, so it will require a lot of memory even for, say, `10^10`. I fear that random `Natural` numbers can be much larger than `10`. I can't remember how to tell quickcheck to limit the range.

Answer (score 0):

As *chi* remarks, the `Nat` type represents numbers as recursive data structure. I *think* that it's isomorphic to `[()]`, but I could be mistaken...

AFAICT, the conversion functions, as well as `recNat`, aren't tail recursive, so when working with something like `10^10`, they'd be building up thunks for billions of elements. It's not too surprising that you get a stack overflow from larger numbers.

You can tell QuickCheck to limit the range of the values generated. The `choose` function is the general-purpose solution to this problem, but AFAICT `Natural` doesn't have a `Random` instance. Instead, you might be able to use `chooseEnum`, since `Natural` *does* have an `Enum` instance.

A few years back I was also [dabbling with natural numbers (and associated ideas)](https://github.com/ploeh/FAlgebras) in a like fashion. Here's a property I wrote of multiplication:

```
testProperty "Multiplication" $ do
  x <- choose @Integer (0, 25)
  y <- choose (0, 25)
  return $ x * y === toNum (multiplyF (fromNum x) (fromNum y))
```

I didn't base my QuickCheck properties on `Natural` since I used `choose`. This enabled me to tell QuickCheck to only pick numbers greater than `0`. For multiplication, I had to constrain my integers to be less than `25`, but for other properties, I chose a larger range:

```
testProperty "Increment" $ do
  i <- choose @Integer (0, 1e4)
  return $ i + 1 === toNum (incF (fromNum i))
```

It's been a few years, so I don't recall exactly why I chose those particular numbers. I was using an older laptop back then, but I don't recall if higher numbers caused my process to overflow, or if it was simply that the tests ran too slowly.